# From a list of dataframes create an output file with specific name and dimensions of each dataframe

Tags: r

I have 2 txt files named `In1B_HZM_VC_Suppl_astaxanthin.txt` and `In2B_HZM_VC_Suppl_beta-carotene.txt` with the following structure:

```
#txt1
Result1 GSK3B   SNCA    SOD2    APP NDUFS7  CAT KCNJ6   TNF PIK3R1  NOS2    EDN1    GSR NOS3    NDUFB6  CASP3
Result2 NDUFS8  NDUFS2  NDUFS3  ETFDH   NDUFV2  SDHA    SDHB    NDUFV1  NDUFS1  NDUFS7
Result3 COQ2

#txt2
Result1 DDR1    CXCL8   MMP1    PTGS2   RPS6KA5 TNNT2
Result2 NQO1    IL1B    CYP1A1  SP1 LEPR    TNF POR HMOX1   TP53    GRIN1   NFE2L2  GJA1
```

After extracting their filepaths from the same folder with:

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/user/Documents/HZM/SourceDatasets", pattern = "*.txt", full.names = T)
```

I have used:

```
myData <- lapply(files, function(x) {
  tryCatch(read.table(x, header = TRUE, sep = '|'), error=function(e) NULL)
})
```

which creates a list of 2 dataframes.

My final goal is to create 2 output tsv files for each of the N source files, named `OutBX_Keyword_GeneCountPerRow.tsv` where “X” is the integer within each source data filename (1, 2 from In1B, In2B),
and “Keyword” is the keyword (e.g. `astaxanthin`) following “VC_Suppl_” in the source data filename.

Example: For the In1B file, the first 6 rows of its output file (OutB1_beta-carotene_GeneCountPerRow.tsv)
will be:

```
Result1 25
Result2 1
Result3 1
Result4 1
Result5 1
Result6 5
```

Im trying something like:

```
for(i in 1:length(myData)){
#Create the txt file
fileConn<-file(paste("OutB",i,files[i],"_GeneCountPerRow.tsv"))

  for(j in 1:nrow(as.data.frame(myData[[i]]))){
    writeLines(c(
      as.data.frame(myData[[j]]
    )))
  }
, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
}
```

The 2 txts [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pn0xiw334ajg5ul/AADAOyok4LDr5kaeYzmIOHXFa?dl=0)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are looking for. Can you post your exact expected output for this list as an edit: `ll <- list(mtcars = mtcars, iris = iris)`?

Comment: If you check my txts you will see that every rows begins with a "Result" and a number of genes next to it. This are the 2 columns of my expected output. I will attach the files